# Deleting voxel artifacts (averaging small geometry)

Tags: mesh, artifacts

I need help. There is such a mesh. Obtained by importing the *.obj file from the fractal generator into Blender. The fractal generator creates this mesh using voxels. In this case, all sharp edges are obtained with this kind of "voxel noise" - sharp peaks, notches, zigzags, holes and other artifacts. This is similar to what we see in Photoshop when we look at the sharp edge of an object in an image when zoomed in greatly. The challenge is to rebuild this mesh so that the large and medium shapes are preserved, but these edge artifacts are gone. Is it possible? It seems that the most logical way would be some smoother, which would completely destroy all small geometry, averaging the position of the verticles. That would suit me. However, the modifiers that I tried (remesh, decimate, all 3 smoothers) do not give satisfactory results — they do not destroy small details, or if they do, then almost nothing remains of the original shape. And I would like, if possible, to do this without manual selection of verticles in artifacts regions, since in some cases the shape can be quite complex. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try Merge by Distance (Alt+M) and play with value (left-down corner of 3Dviewport) or Limited Disolve (X). To let us try to test - crop some segment of your mesh and delete the rest (so file is lighter) and attach blend  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Thank you, that would be great. Made the file several times lighter: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=zBzSoX8n" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/zBzSoX8n/)

Comment: Thanks. Please attach given code into your Question via edit, not in comment section.

Comment: "Merge by Distance" requires the vertices to be closer together in problem areas than in good places. But my mesh is uniform. This can be corrected if, for example, I first make a Decimate by angle between the faces (5-10 degrees, for example). I tried this, but so far the result has not pleased me, to be honest — edge continue to be ragged. Perhaps I am missing some subtle point.

Comment: Add downloading link in original question — done.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer ...*

---

### v01_Vertex Group

I wanted to isolate mess on edge by curvature with **Pointiness** node (only for *Cycles*), *Bake* ...

[image]

... and use this texture for **VertexWeightProximity** modifier to convert into vertex group to be used as mask for *Smooth modifier*.

[image]

---

### v02_Sculpt Mask

Similar technique can be achieve by Sculpt mode. Expand by Curvature didn't work for this, but in the same menu is **Dirty Mask** that worked. So probably easier way to isolate ...

[image]

---

### Smoothing

... but even separation was successful, using *Smooth modifier* (for vertex group) or *Smooth Filter* (for sculpt mask), it failed at the end for the same reason ... topology is too bad to get rid of those things.

Even I tried *Remesh > Blocks* to get even distribution without small artefacts and than *Smooth* modifier (or any of a smooth modifier).

Sorry

So, probably only one advice I how - try [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net) app that is announcing nice optimisation features specifically for thouse issues. But I don't have an experience to navigate you more.

Comment: Vklidu, thanks. I'll keep trying. At least I am now armed with this two methods of identifying bad areas, they were not known to me. Yes, Smoother works poorly, I need a tool that is less dependent on topology. I want to try Decimate, it has the ability to work with vertex groups. And I'll look at other software too. Thanks!